# W7P ListBox doesn't stay scrolled in the emulator

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, scroll

I have a ListBox in a xaml page for a Windows Phone 7 app. It starts out empty, then I populate it with some items once they are retrieved from a web service. So far that all works fine - the items show up in the list and all seems fine. The problem I have is when I try to drag the list to scroll to the bottom (in the emulator): I can scroll down, but as soon as I release the mouse button the list springs back to the top as though I hadn't scrolled it at all. Any insights into why it would behave this way?

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!-- EDIT: the problem was "Auto" here should have been "*" -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- removed other element for brevity -->

    <ListBox Name="InfoBoardListBox" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="InfoBoardListBox_SelectionChanged"
              Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="26.667" />
</Grid>
```

And the method that populates the list:

```
    foreach (InfoBoard entry in boards.Values) {
        item = new ListBoxItem();
        item.Content = entry.Name;
        item.Name = entry.Id.ToString(); //used to tell which entry was clicked
        InfoBoardListBox.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the Height of the second row to `*` instead of `Auto`; I think it's to do with the size that the ListBox thinks it is vs. the available space.

Comment: That looks to have fixed the problem. I had looked for some sort of info on what exactly `Auto` and `*` are supposed to do, so far with no luck. From this example it looks like `Auto` says to figure out the size once during the initial page load, and `*` says figure it out whenever something changes.

Comment: In the context of a RowDefinition, **Auto** means make the row as high as it's contents, but no higher. `Star` is a proportion of the available space (i.e after any fixed or Auto height rows). If you have two rows both set to `*`, then each will have half of the height. There's some documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype.aspx

Comment: That makes sense then. The ListBox height would have been set to around 0 since it had no contents, and either isn't resizing when items are added, or is resizing off the bottom of the screen. If the latter, it would always have enough space (some of it off-screen) to show all the items, which would explain them springing back into place. * is definitely the behaviour I want: a listbox that takes up exactly the remaining height on the screen.